# 50013: Missing Permissions- Discord bot is unable to ban/kick even with the highest priority role, and every single permission given to them

Tags: python, discord, bots

I was coding it with python, and tried several different renditions of it like..

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def clean(ctx):
        guild=ctx.message.guild
        for member in tuple(guild.members):
                ## Try to find the role and skip those higher
                role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'leader', ctx.message.guild.roles)
                if role in member.roles:   
                        print("skip leader")
                ## Not sure how to check other roles before moving on.
                else:
                        await member.kick()

bot.run('Nzc1MTg3MDQwNTg0MDczMjU2.X6irMA.0Wb-sCQRTs-dfnhlGzKNYL5RRfw')
```

or this

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def clean(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    for member in tuple(guild.members):
        try:
            await member.kick()
        except:
            continue
```

and one of the last ones i tried before resorting to making this thread....

```
    @client.command(pass_context=True)
    async def clean(ctx):
            logchannel = client.get_channel(739058160291020920)
            for member in list(ctx.message.guild.members):
                try:
                    await guild.ban(member)
                    print ("User " + member.name + " has been banned")
                    embed = discord.Embed(
                    colour = discord.Colour.red()
                    )
                    embed.add_field(name="User banned", value=f'{member.name}')
                    await logchannel.send(embed=embed)
                except:
                    pass
```

if anyone can assist me in finding out what the heck the problem is, i'd be eternally grateful; because at the moment, no matter what i do, i can't seem to find out why it wont kick or ban regardless of the bots role being the highest, all of my server channels being checked off instead of x'd out as far as perms go, and the role itself has everything; including admin.

Answer (score 0):

The bot didn't have 'access member list' enabled on the bot settings.